# Primitive Data Types In Java Language

Tags: java

Why Should We Write (L) With Long And( F) With Float And (D) With Double In Java Language. Example float number=190.12f.

Comment: To tell the compiler *please don't act too smart and do some unnecessary conversions / optimizations* :)

Comment: What Is Literals I am Read This Form Document But Still I Will Confuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do NOT have to type `D` for `double` since `double` is the default type for floating point numbers. 
Now the difference between `double` and `float` comes down to precision. Java uses 32 bits to store `float`s and 64 bits for `double`s. 
In fact `double` is a stupid name that has it's origins back to Fortran and it implies ***double precision***.
Exactly the same thing happens with `int` and `long`. `int` is the default type of 32 bits and `long` is 64 bits. So an int can store signed values between `-2^31` and `(2^31)-1` and `long` between `-2^63` and `(2^63)-1` For more info on this, look [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)
So if you want a number to not be treated as the default type you have to somehow let the compiler know. Hense the `L` for `long` and `f` for `float`. 
In fact, when you do something like, `float x = 0.1f` you implicitly cast the `0.1` literal to a `float`. 
This statement is equal to `float x = (float) 0.1`

To get a better understanding on this take a look at this example:

Lets say we have these two variables:

```
float x = 0.1f;
double y = 0.1;
```

What do you think `System.out.println(x == y);` will output? (Take a moment to think about it) 
The answer is: `false` 
Why? Lets see the first 20 digits after the decimal point:

```
0.1f --> 1000000014901161200
0.1  --> 1000000000000000055
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write anything. If you don't end a numeric literal with a suffix to specify its type explicitly, it will be assumed by default to be `int` or `double` (based on whether or not it contains a decimal point).

If you want your literal to be treated as a non default type, such a long, you must specify it explicitly (for example with `L`). Sometimes you are forced to specify the type explicitly - for example the literal 10000000000 won't pass compilation, since it's too large for an `int`, so you have to write 10000000000L in order for the compiler to treat it as a `long`.

Comment: What Is Literals I am Read This Form Document But Still I Will Confuse.

Comment: @RKKadi 1000, 104.3, 300000000L are all numeric literals

Comment: Means Any Value Which Were Assign To Our Primitive Data Types